# Why does my PyTorch installed with anaconda need root privilege to run on cuda GPU?

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I use a 1080Ti and set up my environment as follows:

1. Installed ubuntu 16.04, Nvidia driver 384.130, CUDA-8.0
2. Installed anaconda
3. Created an environment and installed PyTorch with `conda install pytorch==0.4.0 torchvision cudatoolkit=8.0 -c pytorch`

When I run a PyTorch code on `cuda:0`, a `cuda runtime error (30)` error occurs. I did some searching and it returns that I need to run with `sudo`. [[link to the solution](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9536)] It worked when I ran the code with root privileges.

But is there any other solution? I cannot always do this on a server where I do not have root access.

Comment: The solution you link to contains the answer to your question: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9536#issuecomment-421172055

Comment: reinstall the nvidia drivers.